# A Tool to practice Categories / Allegories

Tags: category-theory

Is there any handy tool to practice Categories / Allegories, in the sense that for a defined Category, it is possible to check the result of an operation application.

For example, a tool which provides me a (preferably visual) result of pullback/pushout operation application over the specified sets and relations in Rel Category.

Thanks

Comment: I don not know why CAT people giving negative score to this question?! Is this question irrelevant?! I am looking for a tool that uses category theory in application. like something that can compute (if computable) the categorical operations for a provided category!

Comment: I also do not understand. Please see my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very quick answer, since i am on a satelite connection (very expensive).
[Here](http://www.j-paine.org/cgi-bin/webcats/webcats.php) you have an interactive tool for the category of finite sets.
[Wildcats](http://wildcatsformma.wordpress.com/) is my (free) package for Mathematica which can be used to do some calculations and visualizations in category theory.

Comment: I got a problem installing wildcat in walfram mathematica: what do you mean by  `$BaseDirectory` or `$UserBaseDirectory` that I should copy the wildcats files in?

Comment: I got it, I needed to copy the files inside the mathimatica application package under the folder AddsOn > Application

Comment: @qartal yes, you have to type $BaseDirectory, or $UserBaseDirectory in Mathematica and see what folder location it gives back to you. Then place the package in that folder. These are standard operations for Mathematica users. Search the help file for $BaseDirectory to get more info.

Answer (score 0):

GDCD is is another Tool for practicing CAT theory ([here is the link](http://www.mta.ca/~rrosebru/project/gdct/index.html))